# Old javascript app file preventing new javascript from being read

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to use a javascript autocomplete function.

I'm loading the following files at the top of the HTML file.

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

However, I'm still getting this error: `App.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`. It's looking in my javascript file for the application.

I've actually tried to add the autocomplete script to that javascript file, but it's not solving the problem.

I'm new to Javascript so this could be a dumb question, but I legitimately have no idea how to solve it.

Here is the top of my template in loading the files:

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static from static %}

<link 

    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" >
    </script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Static is loading my jquery file.

Comment: You need to load jquery before you load jquery-ui

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that. Do I just put the line before the other one in the HTML?

Comment: I'm loading my jquery files like this: {% load static from static %} in Django template

Comment: The script loads are in the wrong order, jquery.min.js has to be before jquery-ui.js.

Comment: @Barmar The error went away. I'm getting that the request for autocomplete is canceled.